# Поиск одинакового ключа значение в 2-х словарях и запись совпадения в новый словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Есть два словаря, нужно сравнить ключ значение в обоих словарях и совпадение 
записать в новый словарь.

```
operator_one = { 1: 'pass',
             2: 'break',
             3: 'print',
             4: 'yield',
             5 :'try' ,
             }

operator_two = { 1: 'pass',
             2:'global',
             3: 'yield',
             4: 'print',
             5: 'try',
             }


def operator_important(operator_one, operator_two):
"""Поиск одинаковых элементов в словаре и словаре и запись в словарь."""
operator_main = {}
for key, values in operator_one.items:
    if key, values in operator_two.items:
        operator_main[key] = values
return operator_main

d = operator_important(operator_one, operator_two)print(d)
```

Comment: Нужно найти те, у которых ключ и значение совпадают? Добавьте в вопрос ожидаемый результат

Comment: Да которые совпадают ключ и значение и записать все это в новый словарь, через цикл for .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собрать ключи обоих словарей и перебрать их:

```
operator_one = {
    1: 'pass',
    2: 'break',
    3: 'print',
    4: 'yield',
    5: 'try',
}

operator_two = {
    1: 'pass',
    2: 'global',
    3: 'yield',
    4: 'print',
    5: 'try',
}


def operator_important(operator_one, operator_two):
    """Поиск одинаковых элементов в словаре и словаре и запись в словарь."""

    operator_main = dict()
    all_keys = set(list(operator_one.keys()) + list(operator_two.keys()))

    for key in all_keys:
        # Если ключ есть в обоих словарях, и значение по ключу одинаковое
        if key in operator_one and key in operator_two and operator_one[key] == operator_two[key]:
            operator_main[key] = operator_one[key]

    return operator_main

d = operator_important(operator_one, operator_two)
print(d)  # {1: 'pass', 5: 'try'}
```

---

**Andrey** справедливо заметил, что можно упростить код, например так:

```
def operator_important(operator_one, operator_two):
    """Поиск одинаковых элементов в словаре и словаре и запись в словарь."""

    operator_main = dict()
    
    for key, value in operator_one.items():
        if key in operator_two and value == operator_two[key]:
            operator_main[key] = value

    return operator_main
```

Comment: Спасибо отличное решение, т.е. все через ключи решение здесь?Еще в список вижу преобразование list

Comment: Преобразование в список нужно было из-за ошибки `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_keys' and 'dict_keys'` при `all_keys = set(operator_one.keys() + operator_two.keys())`

Comment: А зачем объединять ключи из двух словарей когда достаточно пройтись по ключам одного, и если этого ключа не будет во втором, то их значения не могут быть равны, ввиду отсутствия второго значения для сравнения?

Comment: @Andrey, потому что :) а если серьезно, то решений у этой задачи куча, а объединение ключей первое что пришло в голову, когда посмотрел на код в вопросе. А так, конечно, можно было сделать как вы предложили

Comment: Если тоже самое сделать через *args, мне отдельно вопрос задать?

Comment: @ДенисЛатыпов, задавайте :)

Answer (score 2):

Через генератор покомпактней будет.

```
operator_one = { 2: 'break',
             1: 'pass',
             3: 'print',
             4: 'yield',
             5 :'try' ,
             }

operator_two = { 1: 'pass',
             2:'global',
             3: 'yield',
             4: 'print',
             5: 'try',
             }

d = {key: operator_two[key] for key in operator_one
     if operator_one[key] == operator_two.get(key)}
print(d) # {1: 'pass', 5: 'try'}
```

По факту мы, таким образом, перебираем все ключи из первого словаря и сравниваем их со значением такого-же ключа во втором словаре полученным при помощи метода `get` который, в случае отсутствия во втором словаре используемого ключа, не бросает исключение, а отдает значение `None` (или любое определенное в `operator_two.get(key, <some_value>)`. Ну а генератор он собственно работает как и должен, добавляя пары ключ - значение, соответствующие условию, в новый словарь

Comment: Или так `d = {key: value for key, value in operator_one.items() if key in operator_two and value == operator_two[key]}` если делать честную проверку ключа во втором словаре :)

Comment: Спасибо за варианты, такой вопрос я в генераторе не вижу operator_main?? новый словарь, куда он записывает? вижу только сравнение и перебор, и компактный вид

Comment: @ДенисЛатыпов, в этом случае создается новый словарь `d` Если Вам принципиально название, то можете `d = ` заменить на `operator_main = `

Comment: Благодарен теперь увидел.